# Curve Modifier Deforming my shape

Tags: modeling

I'm adding a curve modifier to my twisted object, targeting the bezier curve, and its making my twisted object much bigger than what it was originally, I have reset the transformations values but it didn't help.

[image]

Comment: maybe select the curve, go in Edit mode, select all and right click > Set Curve Radius?

Comment: yes, that's it! But any idea why it made it so wider in the first place? Something I did wrong?

Comment: you must have scaled your curve, when you've applied the curve's scale it has rescaled the radius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have scaled your curve, when you've applied the scale it has rescaled its vertices radius. So go in *Edit* mode, select all and right click > *Set Curve Radius*, or open the N panel and bring back the *Mean Radius* to 1.